# Ireport Frame Issue

Tags: jasper-reports

In Detail Band, Multiple TextField is present inside a Frame (F1). All textField has `position Type: Float` and `Stretch Type: Relative To Tallest Object` properties set. When long text wraps in textField, frames height changes and its bottom border disappear. I added another frame(F2) having line below frame (F1) with Position Type: Float. This Frame doesn't appear when frame(F1) stretch.

```
<frame>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Opaque" x="387" y="333" width="342" height="24" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#BED4E9"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#BED4E9"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#BED4E9"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </box>
        <line>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="1" width="1" height="22" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </line>
</frame>
```

Any help will be appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

To help you correctly it would be more easy if you posted more of your jrxml but I'll try like this.

put all your text fields in your detail band.
Select all textfields and put into frame.

Select the textboxes and set stretch with overflow and stretch type to relative to talles object. Dont set the textboxes to `position type: float`

Select your frame and go to the border property, select bottom border and set to the width you like.

Now if you would like another frame below that one do the same but set the position type of the frames to float so they get pushed down and dont overlap.

I hope this solves your problem, if not please provide us with more information on your jrxml and/or screenshot of the output.

Good luck!